# StackOverflow Exception on System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverride

Tags: c#, xaml

we've following problem, our Application crashes after a few days without any error message. We found out the reason is a stack overflow exception on the "MeasureOverride" ([MeasureOverride Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.measureoverride?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-windows-controls-virtualizingstackpanel-measureoverride(system-windows-size))) Method.

Now we're facing the problem to find the specific control, which caused this error. Have someone any idea, how to find this control?

Setup:
C# Application (.NET 4.8), runs on a server from one of our customers.

How we found the stack overflow exception:
We created a user mode memory dump and analyze it with WinDbg.

Stack Text from WinDbg:

```
STACK_TEXT:  
00ae2f0c 66328b9b PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.GetSizesForChildWithInset+0x1b
00ae3390 66b914dc PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureChild+0x448
00ae3578 6631f34d PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0xe59
00ae3ad4 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae4030 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae458c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae4ae8 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae5044 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae55a0 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae5afc 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae6058 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae65b4 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae6b10 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae706c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae75c8 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae7b24 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae8080 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae85dc 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae8b38 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae9094 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae95f0 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00ae9b4c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aea0a8 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aea604 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aeab60 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aeb0bc 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aeb618 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aebb74 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aec0d0 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aec62c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aecb88 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aed0e4 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aed640 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aedb9c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aee0f8 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aee654 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aeebb0 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aef10c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aef668 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aefbc4 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af0120 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af067c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af0bd8 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af1134 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af1690 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af1bec 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af2148 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af26a4 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af2c00 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af315c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af36b8 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af3c14 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af4170 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af46cc 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af4c28 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af5184 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af56e0 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af5c3c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af6198 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af66f4 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af6c50 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af71ac 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af7708 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af7c64 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af81c0 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af871c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af8c78 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af91d4 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af9730 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00af9c8c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afa1e8 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afa744 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afaca0 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afb1fc 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afb758 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afbcb4 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afc210 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afc76c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afccc8 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afd224 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afd780 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afdcdc 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afe238 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afe794 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00afecf0 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aff24c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00aff7a8 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00affd04 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b00260 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b007bc 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b00d18 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b01274 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b017d0 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b01d2c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b02288 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b027e4 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b02d40 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b0329c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b037f8 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b03d54 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b042b0 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b0480c 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b04d68 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b052c4 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab
00b05820 6632179f PresentationFramework_ni!System.Windows.Controls.VirtualizingStackPanel.MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32a
```

If u need more information, please tell me, I'm happy about any help.

Kind regards.

---

Comment: Just a note: `MeasureOverrideImpl+0x32ab` - either `MeasureOverrideImpl` has an unusually long body or else this address is not in fact within that method but just in the same neighborhood.